# Appendix Divider Page Roman Numbering

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

I want to continue the numbering of my Appendix in Roman. But if I switch after `\begin{appendices}` to Roman, the divider page is not included. If I switch the numbering before the appendix, my last chapter has Roman numbering, too. Can I switch to Roman beginning with the Divider Page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\newcounter{savepage}
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \pagestyle{plain}

  \tableofcontents
  \cleardoublepage

  \chapter{Introduction}
  \setcounter{savepage}{\arabic{page}}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}\label{ch_conclusion}

  \begin{appendices}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \setcounter{page}{\thesavepage}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \begingroup
        \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
        \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
    }
    \makeatother        
    \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}      
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\cleardoublepage` followed by the change of the pagenumbering before `\begin{appendices}`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\newcounter{savepage}
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \tableofcontents
  %\cleardoublepage
  \chapter{Introduction}

  \cleardoublepage
  \setcounter{savepage}{\value{page}}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}\label{ch_conclusion}

  \cleardoublepage
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \setcounter{page}{\value{savepage}}
  \begin{appendices}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\value{tocdepth}=1}
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \begingroup
        \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
        \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
    }
    \makeatother
    \chapter{Appendix chapter}
    \section{Appendix section}
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to eject the page you need to know the number of, which is done by setting the value of `savepage` after `\cleardoublepage`.

I also suggest not to use `\arabic{page}` or `\thesavepage`, but `\value{page}` and `\value{savepage}`.

Also it's better to use abstract command and to avoid lengthy code in the document body. It's easy to patch `appendices` to do the necessary job. Thus the code in the body is much cleaner.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newcounter{savepage}
% when appendices starts we need to reset the page number
\pretocmd{\appendices}
  {\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{Roman}\setcounter{page}{\value{savepage}}}
  {}{}
% before the appendices we need to setup the toc
\apptocmd{\appendices}
  {%
   \addtocontents{toc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
   \addtocontents{toc}{%
     \begingroup
     \let\string\l@chapter\string\l@section
     \let\string\l@section\string\l@subsection
   }%
  }
  {}{}
% when the appendices end we need to end the group
\pretocmd{\endappendices}{\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}}{}{}

% front matter with Roman numbers
\newcommand{\frontmatter}{%
  \cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{Roman}\pagestyle{plain}%
}
% main matter with arabic numbers (but save the page number up to here)
\newcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \setcounter{savepage}{\value{page}}%
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \pagestyle{headings}% or whatever you like
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\lipsum

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

\lipsum

\chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}\label{ch_conclusion}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{First appendix}

\lipsum

\section{First section}

\lipsum

\chapter{Second appendix}

\lipsum

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]