# Continue page numbering of frontmatter in backmatter

Tags: numbering, page-numbering

I have a document like this:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{book}
    
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
    \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
    
    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    
    \chapter{Abstract}
     [Abstract goes here]
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
     [Introduction goes here]
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \mainmatter
    
    
    \backmatter
    \chapter{Conclusion}
     [Conclusion goes here] 
    
    \end{document}
```

With this document, I have Roman page numbering for `\frontmatter` (containing Abstract and Introduction), and Arabic numbering after that.

What I want is to have `\backmatter` continue the page numbering of frontmatter. At the moment backmatter continues the page numbering of mainmatter.

Comment: Simplest solution would be to switch to roman numbering just before `\backmatter` and manually reset the page counter: `\pagenumbering{roman}\setcounter{page}{xx}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to [Appendix Divider Page Roman Numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511154/4427), with the difference you want to use `\backmatter`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{savedfrontmatterpage}
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \setcounter{savedfrontmatterpage}{\value{page}}%
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
}

\renewcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}%
  \setcounter{page}{\value{savedfrontmatterpage}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Summary}

\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title}

\lipsum

\chapter{Title}

\lipsum

\backmatter

\chapter{Back}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The value of `page` is saved before switching the numbering scheme, then reinstated at `\backmatter`.

Not that I consider this to be a good idea: readers won't be able to find where the back matter starts.

[image]

Comment: Think you for your response. Works perfectly